# Dynamic Form Generation with configurations stored in a database

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I am building a PHP application with `CakePHP 2`. 
I need to have page where a form is displayed.

The form has to be dynamically generated based on configurations stored in a database.

For example :

Database content :

```
{
 {name:"Username",type:"text",label:"Username",validation:("required","minlength:6")},
 {name:"Password",type:"password",label:"Password",validation:("required","minlength:6")},
 {name:"Submit",type:"submit",value:"submit"}
}
```

I want some config like this (*Format Negotiable*) to be stored in a database and based on that a html form would be generated at run-time. If the config is changed at run time the form would also change.
I understand that cakePHP has a form generation component.

So my question is How do I actually get from a config stored in a database to cakePHP form generator and then to the page ?

I was considering the `eval()` function, but I read that it was not really safe, and I am trying to avoid it if possible.

PS:

I will be using `mongodb` for storing the data obtained from the form.

The way that the form configuration is stored in the database is flexible,I am thinking of storing it as a string but that is negotiable.

I am also open to storing the configuration for the form in any database be it a RDBMS or a NoSQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the config from the database (use a data serialization function like `serialize()`, `json_encode()`, or an xml serializer.. whatever is convenient) and build the form using http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

```
// Psuedo-code
$fields = array(
  'fields' => array(
    'name' => 'username',
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Username',
    'validation' => array('...validation config...'),
  )
);

foreach($fields as $formOptions) {
  echo $this->Form->input($formOptions['name'], array('label' => $formOptions['label'])); 
}
```

And so on..

Comment: +1 for this, although i don't think you need to `serialize()` anything, just use `$this->set()` in your controller with all form field configurations and display whichever makes sense using javascript in your view (if the fields that need showing change when the user sees the page) OR you could do some conditional logic in the view and dispaly the propper fields...

anyway, the way i see your problem, it's not strictly 2.0 related, so you can have a look at 1.3 answers as well

Comment: @Bogdan serialize the configuration array to and from the database instead of coming up with his own format and paired parser :)

Comment: oh, that :) yea, sure, that makes sense, obviously :)

Comment: Storing it in a serialized format is kinda cumbersome to edit it , How about storing it in JSON as suggested by @shady using json_encode & json_decode, It seems not to make much of a difference . What are your thoughts on this ?

Comment: @GautamK Json is a type of serialization

Comment: when I said serialized I meant by using `serialize()` method. By the way I am considering storing the config itself in mongodb as it makes for easy retrieval instead of an RDMBS

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there's no easy way to do this. Cake's form generator is the form helper. You can read up on it [here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1384/Creating-Forms). You'll probably have to write your own parser, but the form helper will do a lot for you. I would suggest using the [JSON format](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) so you can easily move between strings stored in the database and indexed arrays within PHP.